# Multiple Facebook IDs for the same user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

i'm crawling user comments and its user ids in public links to build a graph, and i noticed some users have more than one ID. For example, this user have two different IDs: 100000571429851 and 993673107328394.

I'm not using different aps to get the user ids (someone told me user IDs changes between different apps).

Any ideas about how i can get a really unique ID for each user?

Comment: Same sh*t from FB here. This is just ridiculous

Comment: The worst thing is that, recently, accessing a user's profile via his ID, that you got from a graph api call, no longer works. A link such as https://www.facebook.com/[userid] now displays that this content isn't available right now.

Comment: @Jay I have found in a dataset a user id=4e24bd21cb3de37c1d17a3743d3a4716 where same person also have id=4 as an id. You can check it here: https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=4e24bd21cb3de37c1d17a3743d3a4716 , can you please explain how this two ids for the same person?

Comment: Facebook uses multiple IDs. The first IDs were simply numbers. Then came new IDs. But the old ones still work for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 13):

The reason for the different IDs is because this user is using a mixture of v1 and v2 facebook apps. The first ID is the user's personal ID and is returned when someone authorizes the v1 of an app. The second ID is an app scoped-ID and is returned using v2 of the facebook API. See the section in the facebook docs on App-scoped User IDs

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading

> Facebook will begin to issue app-scoped user IDs when people first log into an instance of your app coded against v2.0 of the API. With app-scoped IDs, the ID for the same user will be different between apps.

Comment: is it posible to get second id like 99----- without token.for example we can get 10000..... from 3rd party websites .example http://findfacebookid.com/